# SCSS doesnt work in my HTML file

Tags: html, css, sass

I am working on a website where there are few codes in SCSS format. Is it possible to convert them to CSS. The html file which am working is not recognizing SCSS files. If conversion is not possible, how to make a html file read SCSS.

Answer (score 6):

SCSS is a superset of CSS, HTML will not interpret it by default. You have to transpile it to CSS first. The SCSS transpiler will create CSS files for you, which you can then use in your HTML file.

Here's the official guide: http://sass-lang.com/guide (SCSS and SASS share the same transpiler, so everything described for SASS there will also work for your SCSS files)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possible solutions to your problem. 
You could use something like [Less.js](http://lesscss.org/), which has amazing documentation featured on the website.

I find it easiest however, to use [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) (Provided you have downloaded [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm)) or [sass for command line](https://sass-lang.com/install).

**node-sass**

```
npm i -g node-sass
node-sass [input file] [output file]
```

**sass**

```
sass [input file] [output file]
```

After doing one of the steps above, you can import the given .css file using a link in the head of your html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```